# Cloning elements with hover events?

Tags: jquery

***HTML:***

```
<div id='task-header'>
</div>
<div id='tasks'>
    <a href="#" id ="add">Add</a>
  <ul>
    <li class ="editable">
      <form class='task'>
        <input class='textfield' type='text' />
      </form>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete this row</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id='task-footer'></div>
```

***jQuery:***

```
var item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)").clone(true); // need to clone for new add
$('#add').click(function() {
    var taskItem = item.clone(true);
    $('#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    taskItem.find(':input:text').val("");
    return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    return false;
});

$(".editable").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("editHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("editHover");
});​
```

*JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/

I set my `clone(true)` parameter, but I still cannot get my cloned `<li>`'s to have the hover effect. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1:

```
$(".editable").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("editHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("editHover");
});
var item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)").clone(true); // just change the place 
                                                // of first clone statement
$('#add').click(function() {
    var taskItem = item.clone(true);
    $('#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    taskItem.find(':input:text').val("");
    return false;
});
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Yxpxd/1/)**

#### Solution 2: (with event delegation)

```
var item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)"); // remove clone(true) from here
$('#add').click(function() {
    var taskItem = item.clone(true);
    $('#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    taskItem.find(':input:text').val("");
    return false;
});
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    return false;
});
// use event delegation
$("#tasks").on('hover', '.editable', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') $(this).addClass("editHover");
    else $(this).removeClass("editHover");
});
```

**[DEMO (with event delegation)](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/MHFVd/)**

Comment: Wow thank you for this detailed solutions. I decided to do solution 1.

Answer (score 2):

Simply move the clone call below the handler like below,

```
$(".editable").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("editHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("editHover");
});

var item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)").clone(true); // need to clone for new add
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/6/)

Comment: @VisioN Well If I don't it doesn't add more than once.. I am trying to figure out what is missing. >> http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/4/ << Click Add more than once..

Comment: That's simple. Check what you do when you click: you append cloned once (on init) element. Check mine fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/2/. It clones and appends it on every click.

Comment: Well I know.. but your version will not work when I delete first before add one.. make 0 `li` and click add.. basically nothing to clone at that point right.. I would rather leave the initial clone as it is ;)

Comment: @VisioN aaww I am messed up today.. Thanks.. Updated the post.

Comment: @VisioN mm I think this is what I had problem with when I removed the clone.. Try these steps http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/5/ >> 1. Delete 2. Add 3. Add -> Notice the class editHover getting added to the new `li`'s

Comment: @Vega hi mate, I think your demo have problem, if you delete the first `.editable` and then add again, `hover` don't works.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Check demo now.. >> http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/6/ << I was having issues when I get rid of the initial clone.

Comment: @Vega just fine. Me also suggest that to OP

Comment: Ahhh, that code made me angry. Now the solution should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The event listeners aren't defined yet when you clone the element. Move var `item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)").clone(true);` to the end of your script.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/t67yJ/1/)**

Or use the `.on`/`.live` event delegation and you won't have to clone the listeners, as coder said.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to clone element twice, you can remove one extra `clone` in the first line and attach handlers in delegated-events approach:

```
var item = $("#tasks ul li:eq(0)");

$("body").on("hover", ".editable", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("editHover");
}).on("click", "#add", function() {
    var taskItem = item.clone(true).removeClass("editHover");
    $("#tasks ul").append(taskItem);
    taskItem.find(":input:text").val("");
    return false;
}).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
    return false;
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/t67yJ/7/